# Error after hosting the website using AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I have recently started to use Amazon Web Services to host a very simple web page using Next JS and React. However, once I hosted it on AWS Amplify I seem to get a 503 error with the message being "The request could not be satisfied." from images that are cached from cloudfront. I'm sorry but I am very new to the whole Amazon Web Services eco-system and as far as what I've heard AWS offers multiple services and is best to use very few services when you initially start.

With that in mind here's a brief run down of what I did:

I used AWS Amplify to deploy my website that has no lambda function. Note that all the images that are being served on the website is from the new `<Image />` tag which means that all images are cached in the `/.next/data` folder.

All images are served from Cloudinary as for now.

I didn't change any other settings after deploying the website.

Any help is greatly appreciated!